# Intermodal routing for trucks and traffic

Tags: here-api

Does intermodal routing work for Trucks? The "mode" parameter used in intermodal routing is different for the "mode" used in routing option. I don't see a parameter used specific for trucks and also could I enable traffic in intermodal routing?

Thanks for helping me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Intermodal Routing API currently does not work with trucks. It has different parameters because it is an extension of the Public Transit API.